# jQuery creating objects

Tags: jquery, oop

How would I create an object in jQuery, and then proceed to make a couple of different instances of this object I.e

Create an object named box which holds a variable called color.

And then make a couple of instances of this object with different stored colours.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: I want to explore object-oriented jQuery but do not know how to construct a class and then initialise an object

Comment: use jquery's[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function

Comment: This is a job for javascript alone, jQuery is a framework built on javascript with its focus set on DOM manipulation, javascript is a language.

It has become a common misconception that jQuery is a language itself.

Comment: Maybe this might help? [3 ways to define a JavaScript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)

Answer (score 46):

Another way to make objects in `Javascript` using `JQuery`, getting data from the **dom** and pass it to the object **Box** and, for example, store them in an array of **Boxes**, could be:

```
var box = {}; // my object
var boxes =  []; // my array

$('div.test').each(function (index, value) {
    color = $('p', this).attr('color');
    box = {
        _color: color // being _color a property of `box`
    }
    boxes.push(box);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 11):

May be you want this (oop in javascript)

```
function box(color)
{
    this.color=color;
}

var box1=new box('red');    
var box2=new box('white');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AeFMF/)

[**For more information.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: for this kind of construction use `Box` (in capital letters)

Answer (score 8):

I actually found a better way using the jQuery approach

```
var box = {

config:{
 color: 'red'
},

init:function(config){
 $.extend(this.config,config);
}

};

var myBox = box.init({
 color: blue
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always make it a function

```
function writeObject(color){
    $('body').append('<div style="color:'+color+';">Hello!</div>')
}
```

`writeObject('blue')` ➜ [image]